# Trouble using retrofit and recyclerview in fragment

Tags: android, retrofit

I am not able to load data from retrofit call in recycler view. But it is going into onFailure method.

```
TaskApiInterface taskApiInterface = APIClient.getApiClient().create(TaskApiInterface.class);
            //TaskApiInterface service = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(TaskApiInterface.class);
            Call<TaskData> call = taskApiInterface.getLatestTaskData(50, 0, "-artwork");
            /*Log the URL called*/
            Log.d("URL Called", call.request().url().toString());
            call.enqueue(new Callback<TaskData>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<TaskData> call, @NonNull Response<TaskData> response) {
                    Log.d("CallSuccess", response.raw().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<TaskData> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                    Log.d("CallFail", t.toString());
                    t.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

My api

```
 @GET("api/v1/products/artworks/")
    Call<TaskData> getLatestTaskData(
                                     @Query("limit") Integer limit,
                                     @Query("offset") Integer offset,
                                     @Query("ordering") String ordering);
```

My Stacktrace saying this

```
D/CallFail: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
2019-08-26 14:31:59.402 3556-3556/com.codon.masterpiece W/System.err: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
2019-08-26 14:31:59.402 3556-3556/com.codon.masterpiece W/System.err:     at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
```

Comment: your TaskData response model is bad, you are trying to get Int from String. I woul suggest use some auto Json to Java model converter first. Something like this http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Comment: Can you show your `TaskData` model? If you read the error it says you are trying to format a number from an empty string.

Comment: you send wrong code, there is not a problem you must see your code where you use Float.valueOf(STRING)

Comment: I suggest you to perform parsing `String` to `Int` in your application, change your `Int` parameters to `String`. It always saves me when I send and receive data as `String` and then perform parsing fields.

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved it by changing Float and Double to string in my model class.